# Google apps script: using libraries across different scripts giving me different behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using dataframe-js. https://gmousse.gitbooks.io/dataframe-js/content/doc/api/dataframe.html

I have paste the code into a .gs file in a `script1`.

this code works in `script1`.

```
function test(){
  var data =[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]

  var DataFrame = dfjs.DataFrame
 
  var df = new DataFrame(data)

}
```

But when add `script1` as a library into `script2` I can't use the code anymore.

```
function test(){
 
  var data =[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]

  var DataFrame = script1.dfjs.DataFrame
 
  var df = new DataFrame(data)

}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Error   
ArgumentTypeError: Array while expecting DataFrame | Array | Object.
_construct  @ dataframe-js 1.4.3.gs:3167
Wrapper @ dataframe-js 1.4.3.gs:3191
ArgumentTypeError   @ dataframe-js 1.4.3.gs:4517
_build  @ dataframe-js 1.4.3.gs:6813
DataFrame   @ dataframe-js 1.4.3.gs:6665
```

I could just paste the code again. But why doesn't this work? Not sure if it is a `dataframe-js` issue or somehow I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested `console.log(script1.dfjs.DataFrame)` at the client-side, I confirmed that the script works. So, from the error message of `ArgumentTypeError: Array while expecting DataFrame | Array | Object.`, I thought that it might be required to pass the array `data` by value as the string. I thought that the reason for this issue might be due to `this` of library side and client-side are different. So when the following modification is reflected in your situation, what result will you obtain?

#### For library side:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script file of the library side.

```js
function DataFrame(data) {
  return new dfjs.DataFrame(JSON.parse(data));
}
```

#### For client-side:

Please test the following script on the client-side.

```js
function test(){
  var data =[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']];
  var df = script1.DataFrame(JSON.stringify(data));

}
```

Comment: that does work. Why did you change it to a json and back again? why can't you just pass `data` through? i still don't understand it.

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About this issue, from `console.log(script1.dfjs.DataFrame)` and your error message, I thought that the script can be used and `data` might not be able to be used. So I thought that this issue might be due to `this` of library side and client-side are different. So I proposed to send `data` by converting the array object to a string. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.